Are there any issues of shavua (oath) in The Ritual of The Calling of an Engineer (Canada)
In Canada when graduating from engineering, one attends a "secret" ceremony, "The Ritual of The Calling of the Engineer." In this process, the new engineer makes a pledge to prioritize safety over profit and then receives the Iron Ring, which is worn on the pinky finger of the dominant hand.
Is there any issue of shavua or neder associated with reciting this at the ceremony?
The content of the pledge is as follows:

I, ____________, in the presence of these my betters and my equals in
my calling, bind myself upon my honour and cold iron, that, to the
best of my knowledge and power, I will not henceforward suffer or
pass, or be privy to the passing of, bad workmanship or faulty
material in aught that concerns my works before mankind as an
engineer, or in my dealings with my own soul before my Maker.
My time I will not refuse; my thought I will not grudge; my care I
will not deny towards the honour, use, stability and perfection of any
works to which I may be called to set my hand.
My fair wages for that work I will openly take. My reputation in my
calling I will honourably guard; but, I will in no way go about to
compass or wrest judgment or gratification from any one with whom I
may deal.
And further, I will early and warily strive my uttermost against
professional jealousy or the belittling of my working colleagues, in
any field of their labour.
For my assured failures and derelictions, I ask pardon beforehand, of
my betters and my equals in my calling here assembled; praying, that
in the hour of my temptations, weakness and weariness, the memory of
this my obligation and of the company before whom it was entered into,
may return to me to aid, comfort, and restrain.


Not sure I see what is personal - it feels to apply to every single engineer student. I don't see personal details in the OP question

Welcome to MiYodeya Yisroel and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

The force of a shevua is the fact that it is verbally expressed as an intent to perform (or abstain from) an action, without any qualifiers. The Torah applies the halachic effect of a shevua under those conditions.
Paradoxically, if one were to attempt to add some sort of weight, an alternative authority, to the shevua, this would actually detract from the validity of the shevua (see YD 237:6). The question is, if the "oath" in this case is granted weight, according the the quoted formula, through the authority of "my honour and cold iron", does that, in effect, nullify what would have been a legitimate shevua?
I think it's reasonable to assume so. Although it is possible to interpret "my honour" as a euphemism for "the power of my word", I think this is farfetched.
Another alternative may be to pre-emptively declare in the presence of two kosher witnesses, that the oath one is going to declare should be null and void, nothingness, have no validity etc. etc.
It goes without saying that for a practical ruling, CYLOR.

You may also add that neder is focused on the object to restrict or pledge, and in the OP question it is not applicable.
